# Encrypting the Vigenere cipher

Tags: python, vigenere

I'm supposed to create a program that uses a word as the encryption key that behaves like this in the end

```
    $ python vigenere.py
Type a message:
The crow flies at midnight!
Encryption key:
boom
Uvs osck rmwse bh auebwsih!
```

Here is a link to the [Vigenere cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher#)

My main issue is with the encrypting aspect of it.

```
def vigenere_cipher(plaintext, key):
encrypted_string = ''
for i in range(len(key)):
# loop over plaintext by index
    plaintextVal = ord(plaintext)
    # if character in plaintext is alpha do the following:
    keyVal = ord(key[i])
    keyVal = keyVal - 97
    # get alphabet position for character in key

    plaintextChar += chr(keyVal + plaintextVal)
    if plaintextVal >= ord('z')
    #get alphabet position for character in plaintext
        plaintextVal = plaintextVal - 26
        # rotate character from plaintext with a character from the key 
        # convert new position back to a character if you haven't done it already
        # concatenate new character to an encrypted string             


        print PlaintextVal

return encrypted_string
```

I'm getting a bunch of invalid syntax errors throughout and I'm confused on how to go about fixing the code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to fix it is to just take each error as you go. For example, in `if plaintextVal >= ord('z')` you need a `:` at the end of the statement. Then, `print Plaintext` requires the variable `plaintext` to be spelt properly. You will probably get more errors after all the syntax errors have been fixed because you are trying `ord(plaintext)` but you cannot take the `ord` of a string, but only a character.

It looks to me like it would make sense for you to loop over the plaintext instead of the `len(key)`: `for plaintextCharacter in plaintext` and keep track of a different counter for which character in key is to be worked with for each `plaintextCharacter`.